# Flutter flavorizr app name not working on ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, android-flavors

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavorizr package to create flavors in my flutter app.
Everything is working fine for me when running on Android, but iOS is not working as expected (at least as I expect, maybe I am wrong). I am creating an app with two flavors, different app names and icons. Android shows both icons and names correctly, however, iOS just changes the icon, but shows the same name (the original one, not one of the flavors) on both apps. To fix this, I have to change "Bundle display name" in Runner info config (xcode) to a User defined Setting, and manually give a name to each run config.

Is this the expected behaviour or should flavorizr make this config for me (as it does on Android)? If it should do it, what am I missing?

Thx in advance for the help.

I attach my flavorizr config on pubspec.yaml

```
 flavorizr:

  ide: "idea"
  app:
    android:
      flavorDimensions: "flavor-type"
    ios:
  flavors:
    parla:
      app:
        name: "Parla"
        icon: "assets/images/parla/logo.jpg"
      android:
        applicationId: "com.example.parla"
        icon: "assets/images/parla/logo.jpg"
      ios:
        bundleId: "com.example.parla"
        icon: "assets/images/parla/logo.jpg"
    zamora:
      app:
        name: "Zamora"
        icon: "assets/images/zamora/logo.jpg"
      android:
        applicationId: "com.example.zamora"
        icon: "assets/images/zamora/logo.jpg"
      ios:
        bundleId: "com.example.zamora"
        icon: "assets/images/zamora/logo.jpg"
```

Comment: Did you install the additional software needed for iOS as listed in their package page?

Comment: Do you mean Ruby, etc? Yes I did, and I think those are working because the different icons are working on iOS, so the xCode mods are being made I guess. @nvoigt

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved on https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavorizr version 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding some attributes.

It looks like it is expecting some configurations

```
flavorizr:
  ide: "vscode"
  app:
    android:
      flavorDimensions: "flavor-type"
    ios:
      schema: true
```